# append an integer variable to char variable in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new in C++, I have a small project,
I should get 10 numbers from user and then show in result.

so I wrote this code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int counter=1,
        allNumbers;
    float score;
    while(counter <= 10) {
        scanf("%f",&score);
        counter++;
    }

    printf("Your entered numbers are : %s\n",allNumber);
}
```

for example user enter 2 3 80 50 ... and I want show 2,3,80,50,... in result.

But I don't know what should I do !

Comment: looks like C to me. Are you sure you're using C++? Search for "C array" or "C++ vector" on Google.

Comment: @Dave Yes, I trying to learn c++ and this is a basic exam for first chapter.

Comment: @MajAfy Which book are you reading?

Comment: Why is it C if it's teaching C++? Already you're missing out on strong-typing. That `printf` statement is undefined behaviour.

Comment: then you might want to look at `cin` and `cout` which are the C++ way of reading/writing information. Also as I said, look up "C++ vector", which will solve your problem.

Comment: @sftrabbit This is not a book, I read my teacher's booklet

Comment: Can you make it work with only one number? How about two?

Comment: @chris I don't know, my teacher said C++ support all C function and syntax and for first chapter I should use Win32 Console for my applications.

Comment: @MajAfy, C++ doesn't support `int size = 5; int arr[size];` (use a vector or similar instead). C does.

Comment: @Beta for one number I can define a simple variable `number = score` in my loop and then use `printf("You entered %d",number)` but I don't know how can I store 2 or more numbers.

Comment: @MajAfy Tell your teacher that this is bad C++. Yes, it's valid C++, but it's basically just C. There are *many* differences between C and C++. Just because the C library is available, doesn't mean you should use it.

Comment: *"my teacher said C++ support all C function and syntax"*  I am **not** liking this teacher so far...

Comment: @MajAfy Has your teacher taught you about arrays?

Comment: I'll bet arrays are coming up soon. For now, if you can store one number, you can store two just by doing it two times with different variables. That expands out to ten pretty easily. Don't worry if it feels like you're butchering a kitten with how unscalable it looks because you'll probably learn a better way soon.

Comment: @sftrabbit No yet, but I can use, he said I should research in internet and solve this exam ! I'm a web designer and PHP Developer, but I didn't work C until know, and because PHP syntax is very similar to C I think I can learn C++ easily, I installed Visual Studio for first time :-)

Comment: Okay, how would you do this in PHP? The important parts are pretty similar.

Comment: @chris In PHP data type is not important, the operators is important, if I use string operator PHP change the data type of variable to string automatically, so I can use `$allNumbers .= ",".$score;`

Comment: @MajAfy, Yes, I know a bit of PHP. C++ has similar methods you can use. You can start off with a `std::string` and use `+=` and `+` instead of `.=` and `.` to concatenate, and `std::to_string` to convert.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know what book you are using, but the authors appear to teach you C before going into the C++ land. Without discussing their motives, I'll write an answer to be similar to your style of code before discussing an ideal C++ solution.

- You need an array to store your numbers: `double score[10]`
- Array are indexed starting from zero, so change `counter` to start at zero and go to nine (instead of starting at one and going to ten, like you have now)
- Since `score` is an array, use `&score[count]` in the call of `scanf`
- To print ten numbers you need a loop as well. You need a flag that tells you whether or not you need a comma after the number that you print. Add a `printf("\n")` after the loop.

As far as an "ideal" C++ solution goes, it should look close to this one:

```
istream_iterator<double> eos;
istream_iterator<double> iit(cin); 
vector<double> score;
copy(iit, eos, back_inserter(score));
ostream_iterator<double> oit (cout, ", ");
copy(score.begin(), score.end(), oit);
```

However, discussing it would remain hard until you study the C++ standard library and its use of iterators.

Comment: I think the asker is going to be a little shocked by how vastly different that code is. :D

Comment: Thank you but this code is professional and I cannot analyse for my teacher, but your description was good, thanks

Comment: Well, it comes in time. It's not that important to know when beginning, but it's definitely good to keep in the back of your mind and come back to when you're familiar with the language and have looked into iterators.

Comment: That's why I put the code at the end. The OP is very close to a C solution - all he needs is the four changes described in the "bullet points" above the code. The code is there as an illustration of what he will be writing once he's done with the course.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, My only C++ course was far from that at the end of it :( To be fair, it was a grade 11 one with no prerequisites.

Comment: @MajAfy I did not change your code on purpose - you're too close, I don't want to spoil it for you. If you follow the four steps in the description, you'll get your own code working pretty quickly. The snippet of code at the end is an illustration of how the same thing can be done using full strength of the C++ standard library - something to look for as you learn the language.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by declaring an array of ten numbers.
your code goes here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int counter=0;
float allNumbers[10];
while(counter < 10) {
    scanf("%f",&allNumbers[counter]);
    counter++;
        }

printf("Your entered numbers are : \n");
counter=0;
while(counter < 10) {
    printf("%f , ",allNumbers[counter]);
    counter++;
        }
}
```